# X marks the what?

Tags: wordplay, knowledge, cryptic-crosswords

In the following clues, a certain term been replaced with $X$. Find out the meaning of $X$ and solve the crossword.

> [image]

**Down**

> 1. Deadly $X$ (5)
> 2. White heroine or cocaine (4)
> 3. Introduction of good old $X$ (4)

**Across**

> 4. $X$ in screwy nail is $X$ object (5)
> 5. $X$s scrapped behind engine driver's head for $X$ group (9)
> 6. Unopened salad central solely to leaders of $X$ equation (3'1 3)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Building very *heavily* on PilsNot3's answer (upvoted), $X$ is

> Heavy Metal

1D. Deadly $X$ (5)

> Fatal (Fat Aluminium)

4A. $X$ in screwy nail is $X$ object (5)

> Anvil is a heavy metal object (Vanadium in nail anagrammed)

6a. Unopened salad central solely to leaders of $X$ equation (3'1 3)

> Ohm's law. Coleslaw -> oleslaw -> take out le from so**le**ly, add **h**eavy **m**etal

5a. $X$s scrapped behind engine driver's head for $X$ group (9)

> I can't see past Rémi Henry's suggestion of Motörhead, Possible wordplay: Heavy - Vanadium - Yttrium = Hea. Engine = Motör. D = Driver's head. This makes 2d, snöw, but given the an̈swer this seems to be Ök.

Comment: All cörrect! :D

Answer (score 8):

**Partial**

The identity of $ X $ is

> **Metal**

Solutions to the cryptic clues:

1D. Deadly $X$ (5)

> **FATAL**(?) - deadly, is also the name of [several](https://www.metal-archives.com/bands/Fatal/9563) [metal](https://www.metal-archives.com/bands/Fatal/117492)  [bands](https://www.metal-archives.com/bands/Fatal/3540278006)

2D. White heroine or cocaine (4)

> **SNOW** - Snow White, and “snow” is slang for cocaine.

3D. Introduction of good old $X$ (4)

> **GOLD** - metal, G(ood) + OLD

4A. $X$ in screwy nail is $X$ object (5)

> **ANVIL** - metal object, (NAIL)* around V (vanadium, a metal)

5A. $X$s scrapped behind engine driver's head for $X$ group (9)

> **MOTORHEAD**(?) (suggested by Rémi Henry) - metal group, MOTOR (engine driver) + HEAD, not sure about “Metals scrapped” though

6A. Unopened salad central solely to leaders of $X$ equation (3'1 3)

> **???’? LAW** - Some kind of law relating to metals - maybe LEN’S LAW, or OHM’S LAW (suggested by ZanyG)? Though not sure how either fit the cryptic clue... We do have SLAW = “salad,” but the rest I have no idea

Comment: 5A : rot13(ZBGBEURNQ) ?

Comment: What's rot13(Yra'f Ynj)? Do you mean (Yram'f Ynj)?

Comment: Considered rot13(Buz'f Ynj)? Not sure if it fits with the cryptic, but at least it's three letters.

Comment: Could it refer to rot13(Zbu'f ynj ? Nygubhtu gung'f ernyyl n fpnyr gung eryngrf gb uneqarff bs ryrzragf) and I'm not sure about the apostrophe in that case either. Would rot13(ebpx) fit the same pattern as it's quite similar in meaning